# Weed Wacker Not Running Properly

Tags: landscaping, engine

I have a Remington weed wacker that is ~2 years old.  It worked great for the first 2 or 3 months but then I could not get it to work properly.  I have tried new gas, new plug, adjusting the idle on the carburetor and checking the screen in the carburetor and it still does not run properly.  It starts okay and will run somewhat decently on half choke but it stalls almost immediately after turning the choke off.  I have included a video hosted on my Google Drive account of it running (my 7 year old was the videographer so please forgive the jitters and finger in view lol)

Any thoughts on what it could be?

[Video of my weed wacker](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxJjaCFuo-5LQ0d6QUVhejk0Ulk/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: bad Fuel Flow or bad fuel . Is that a 2 stroke ? Bad Oil/Fuel Mixture.

Comment: take it back to the dealer and ask them to give it a tune up.   Oh wait, the "dealer" was Home Depot? Take it to the Stihl dealer and tell them you plan to leave with a working weedwacker.  You will :)

Comment: You are running it in the horizontal position, maybe the carburetor is not filling properly. Does it operate this way in the vertical position?